# How to call assertEquals with Double Epsilon/Precision in Kotlin?

Tags: java, testing, junit, kotlin

I was wondering, in Kotlin, is there the possibility to call the equivalent of the java method:

```
assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double precision)
```

because everytime I'm getting this method instead

```
assertEquals(expected: T, actual: T, message: String)
```

And i can't find the one with the precision parameter.
Calling the Java one should be fine too I guess.

My call to the method:

```
assertEquals(5000.00, calculateCouponAmount(basicFaceValue, basicInterestRate, amortizationBullet, couponNumber1), 0.01)
```

I'm getting an error because 0.01 gets in the "message" field

Comment: Can you show your attempted call to the method? Because that should work fine.

Comment: You can also create your own extension function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured it out!

This is how it's done

```
import org.junit.*
import Kotlin.Test.assertEquals

Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual, precision) // to use the jUnit standard one
assertEquals(expected, actual, message) // to use the Kotlin one
```

Comment: How does that consider the precision at all in the Kotlin version?

Comment: It doesn't in pure Kotlin, that's why you need to use Assert.assertEquals

Comment: `// to use the Kotlin one` kind of implies that this is equivalent when it's not, so I think it should be changed

Comment: @Stefano.Maffullo it now does. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find one, so I created my own set of functions:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal
import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.test.asserter

internal fun assertEquals(expected: Double, actual: Double?, epsilon: Double, message: String? = null) {
    asserter.assertNotNull(null, actual)
    asserter.assertTrue({ messagePrefix(message) + "Expected <$expected>, actual <$actual>, should differ no more than <$epsilon>." },
            abs(expected - actual!!) <= epsilon)
}

internal fun assertEquals(expected: BigDecimal, actual: BigDecimal?, epsilon: Double, message: String? = null) {
    asserter.assertNotNull(null, actual)
    asserter.assertTrue({ messagePrefix(message) + "Expected <$expected>, actual <$actual>, should differ no more than <$epsilon>." },
            (expected - actual!!).abs().toDouble() <= epsilon)
}

internal fun assertEquals(expected: Double, actual: BigDecimal?, epsilon: Double, message: String? = null) {
    asserter.assertNotNull(null, actual)
    asserter.assertTrue({ messagePrefix(message) + "Expected <$expected>, actual <$actual>, should differ no more than <$epsilon>." },
            abs(expected - actual!!.toDouble()) <= epsilon)
}

internal fun messagePrefix(message: String?) = if (message == null) "" else "$message. "
```

Answer (score 3):

It is now included in the official API for Double and Float:

```
fun assertEquals(
    expected: Double,
    actual: Double,
    absoluteTolerance: Double,
    message: String? = null
): Unit

fun assertEquals(
    expected: Float,
    actual: Float,
    absoluteTolerance: Float,
    message: String? = null
): Unit
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-equals.html

Answer (score 2):

Just check to make sure you're importing the correct class that has the desired `assertEquals` method on it. Other than that you may want to verify that the `calculateCouponAmount()` method returns a `Double`.